# Syncing Spring Boot Contexts Startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We have two ports are exposed 8081 and 8080 in our application. This creates two contexts in the same applicaiton which causes problems such as when the 8080 port is not ready, 8081 port can respond to requests. I want to know whether is there some smart ways to sync those ports so I can rely that application has successfully started whether 8080 or 8081 port responds? In my some situation I want to respond to ping request OK if my cache is loaded correctly.

Comment: By default there is only a single port exposed, unless you have specified that your management part has to be on a different port.

Comment: Thanks changed the question accordingly. Do you know how can I solve this issue?

Comment: This question is not clear.

Comment: In which part can I help you with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we solved this problem by listening to `ApplicationReadyEvent` at each of the endpoints we wanted it to not respond with 200, instead we respond with 4xx status code until the event is received.